# Sharepoint session timeout alert for logged in users(Site minder Integrated)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, siteminder

We have a sharepoint 2010 application configured with CA SiteMinder for authentication. I need to understand if there is anyway to alert an user if the session is timing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a control that retrieves the number of seconds (say n) the session is still valid, outputs Javascript with a setTimeout to display the alert n-60 seconds in the future to display the message 1 minute before the session expires.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SiteMinder.  Is there a way to query Siteminder to find out when the session will be invalid at any given time?